# Undefined Array Manipulation

Tags: javascript

probably a simple one here but just wondering what the best way to get this working is. I'm currently getting the console.log for purchaseUnitArray as undefined and I know something doesn't look quite right. I simply want to return an array of purchaseUnits, with the individual charity non_profit id and split amount in each. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```js
const charities = [948, 182, 584];
const amount = 1000;

const splitPurchaseUnits = (nonprofit_id, amount) => {
  const purchaseUnit = {
    custom_id: `${nonprofit_id}`,
    amount: {
      value: amount,
      currency_code: "USD",
      breakdown: {
        item_total: {
          currency_code: "USD",
          value: amount,
        },
      },
    },
  };
};

const purchaseUnitArray =
  charities &&
  charities.map((charity) => {
    return splitPurchaseUnits(charity, amount / charities.length);
  });

console.log(purchaseUnitArray, "array");
```

Comment: `return purchaseUnit`

Comment: no sample of expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to **[implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body)** like:

```js
const charities = [948, 182, 584];
const amount = 1000;

const splitPurchaseUnits = (id) => ({
  custom_id: id,
  amount: {
    value: amount / charities.length,
    currency_code: 'USD',
    breakdown: {
      item_total: {
        currency_code: 'USD',
        value: amount,
      }
    }
  }
});

const purchaseUnitArray = charities.map(splitPurchaseUnits);
console.log(purchaseUnitArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just looks like you're not returning the `purchaseUnit` at the end of your function! You can either do:

```
return purchaseUnit;
```

or instead:

```
return {
  custom_id: nonprofit_id,
  // etc
}
```

(or completely remove the return like the other answer shows).

As a heads up, it looks like there's a missing bracket at the end of `splitPurchaseUnits`. Not sure if a bug or accident in creating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return some value from the function `splitPurchaseUnits` else return `undefined` internally by JS.

```js
const charities = [948, 182, 584];
const amount = 1000;

const splitPurchaseUnits = (nonprofit_id, amount) => {
  const purchaseUnit = {
    custom_id: `${nonprofit_id}`,
    amount: {
      value: amount,
      currency_code: "USD",
      breakdown: {
        item_total: {
          currency_code: "USD",
          value: amount,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return purchaseUnit;
};

const purchaseUnitArray =
  charities &&
  charities.map((charity) => {
    return splitPurchaseUnits(charity, amount / charities.length);
  });

console.log(purchaseUnitArray, "array");
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do that this way:

```js
const charities = [948, 182, 584];
const amount    = 1000;

const splitPurchaseUnits=(charities,amount)=>charities.map(nonprofit_id=>
     ({ custom_id: `${nonprofit_id}`
      , amount: 
        { value: amount
        , currency_code: 'USD'
        , breakdown: 
          { item_total: 
            { currency_code: 'USD'
            , value: amount
      } } } }))


console.log( splitPurchaseUnits(charities, amount) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```